# How do I use a phantom section in conjunction with nameref?

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, cross-referencing

To have the bibtex bibliography properly in the toc I use a `\phantomsection` and give it a label. Then I add it to the toc using `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}`. You can see a full example below for clarification.

Now I'd like to reference the bibliography automatically by it's heading string (in my case this heading is "References"). If I change the heading to e.g. "Bibliography" or "Sources" it is supposed to change the reference to that string on it's own. The problem here is that `\nameref` always uses the heading of the last real section (in my case that is "Some Section").

That problem applies to all bibliography-style lists such as the list of tables, list of figures and list of abrevations. Do you have a solution/workaround for that problem?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref,url}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}

\section{Some Section}
Some uninterstion citation: \cite{random} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Below this line it gets interesting %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Some text \nameref{refer}. % <--- This nameref produces "Some Section" instead of "References"

\phantomsection \label{refer}
\addtocounter{section}{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\Alph{section}}References}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an option in KoMa-script classes to get a numbered bibliography section; but it would be difficult to provide the label, so here's a way out: put the following code in the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\bib@heading{%
  \section{\refname}\label{refer}%
  \@mkboth{\sectionmarkformat \refname}{\sectionmarkformat \refname}%
  }
\makeatletter
```

You don't have to issue neither `\phantomsection` nor `\addcontentsline`, just `\bibliography{test}`.

However, since the name of the bibliography section is already available as `\refname`, I'd suggest

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref,url}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}

\renewcommand{\refname}{References\label{refer}}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\cite{random} % bibtex wants this
The cited papers can be found in section~\nameref{refer}.

\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

The same strategy works for `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`; the relevant option to add is

```
listof=numbered
```

and the commands to renew are

```
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of Figures\label{figurelist}}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{List of Tables\label{tablelist}}
```

For `nomencl` the command is

```
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Nomenclature\label{nomencl}}
```

but for getting it numbered and in the table of contents there's no option in KoMa-Script, but there is for the package:

```
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
```

Comment: For some reason `\refname` produces the Sting "Referencesrefer" when I use it like this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/798194/ Also this solution does not solve the same problem with list of tables, figures and abbreviation. Same for the first solution but that should be adaptable for thoese lists if I get my head wrapped around the respective package definitions.

Comment: @con-f-use See edit for how to make this work with hyperref.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. Still a solution, that works for the other lists would be nice. Maybe I will just use `\ref` instead.

Comment: What other lists? For the list of figures the relevant name is `\listfigurename` (`\listtablename` for tables) and the same strategy as for `\refname` should work.

Comment: Yes, thanks again! Of course you're right, I came to realise that. For the list of nomenclature provided by the `nomencl` package that would be `\nomname` - just in case someone wonders. The `nomencl` package does not provide a `totocnumbered` option, just `intoc` which causes the abbrevatiobns to appear in toc but does no enumeration. `listof=totocnumbered` does the same for list of tables and figures.